# <a> download rename not working

Tags: html

currently I am trying to make an `<a>` tag that will download an xml from a link and I also want that file renamed. I know `<a download="test.xml" href="http://www.somesite.com/anothertest.xml">` is supposed to be used to create this effect but the file name remains "anothertest.xml" rather than changing to "test.xml" whenever I download it any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: I've heard of issues using the download attribute when the original file is not on the same server/domain as the link. Could that be an issue in your case?

Comment: In this case it is in a different domain I'll give that a try

Comment: Probably it won't work, but try to change `download="test.xml"` to `download="test"`.

Comment: -Alex Howes, That was it I tried it on the same server and it worked perfectly fine thanks!

Comment: @CodyAnderson great! I'll write it as an answer so anyone else coming across this can see it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers don't allow the use of the download attribute to rename a file when the file is from an external server/domain.

Comment: I would specify that you can use the download attribute you just can't use download="newname" in order to rename the file if it is from an external server/domain